# Image appears blank in Windows

Tags: images, image-quality

I have the following image

[image]

This image can be seen properly only on OSX, but can not be seen in Windows. I need to edit this image in Photoshop or illustrator, but I am not able to find the issue. I tried various image correction tools, but it still appear blank in Windows. Any idea why this is happening?

**Edit:**
Just checked this question on a windows machine too. The image doesn't appear in Windows at all.

Comment: Possible relevant thread: [How to open Mac image formats on Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/15190/how-to-open-mac-image-formats-on-windows)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but none of the solution works. This image is not tiff, it's a simple png file. I have tried many image viewer, but it still doesn't appear in windows in any of them. I can't even see the image posted in the question, if I am on windows.

Comment: wish I could help you, but I'm on a Windows machine, and I'm not seeing any image...

Comment: @PieBie This is the link - http://i.stack.imgur.com/GEnvy.png

Comment: I am not sure... I would try posting this in http://superuser.com/. Tried searching for a solution but can't find anything relevant. The only thing I can think of is that the image doesn't have an extension at the end of it or an image file type that is not supported in windows.

Comment: @AndrewH this image has .png extension if that's what you're talking about. WRT image file type, I thought image types are universal everywhere.

Comment: @noob images are universal that is why I am not sure why they're not showing up. I am sure your image does have an extension. I just pointed out my only thoughts of why it would not be showing up. Maybe the file is corrupted?